# Insert previous value of field using INSERT INTO and subquery SELECT

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-insert

I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, val INTEGER, previousval INTEGER)
```

I want to store the value `val` and automatically copy the previous value into the column `previousval`:

```
id  val previousval
1   100 NULL
2   200 100
3   300 200
```

I tried the following query and SQLite gives me an error message I don't understand.

```
INSERT INTO test as test1 (id, val, previousval) VALUES (NULL, 1, (SELECT test2.val FROM test AS test2 WHERE test2.id<test1.id ORDER BY test2.id DESC LIMIT 1))
> no such column: test1.id
```

I tried another query:

```
INSERT INTO test (id, val, previousval) VALUES (NULL, 100, (SELECT test2.val FROM test AS test2 WHERE test2.id<id ORDER BY test2.id DESC LIMIT 1)) 
INSERT INTO test (id, val, previousval) VALUES (NULL, 200, (SELECT test2.val FROM test AS test2 WHERE test2.id<id ORDER BY test2.id DESC LIMIT 1)) 
INSERT INTO test (id, val, previousval) VALUES (NULL, 300, (SELECT test2.val FROM test AS test2 WHERE test2.id<id ORDER BY test2.id DESC LIMIT 1))
```

The result is not what I expect and I don't understand why.

```
id  val previousval
1   100 NULL
2   200 NULL
3   300 NULL
```

I use sqlite-amalgamation-3310100.
I also use SQLiteStudio for testing.

How to automatically copy the value of a field into a column using `INSERT INTO`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your attempt is that you are trying to correlated the subquery with a value that is not yet inserted. That can't work.

You could just do:

```
insert into test as test1 (id, val, previousval) 
values(
    null, 
    1, 
    (select val from test order by id desc limit 1)
)
```

Note: if `id` is an auto-incremented key (as it looks like), then just skip that column when inserting:

```
insert into test as test1 (val, previousval) 
values(
    1, 
    (select val from test order by id desc limit 1)
)
```

Bottom line, I would not actually recommend storing that derived information in the table itself: for example, if `val` is updated, then you need some additional processing to reset the following record.

You can easily compute that information on the fly when needed, or put in a view. If your version of SQLite supports window functions:

```
select id, val, lag(val) over(order by id) previousval from mytable
```

In earlier versions:

```
select
    t.id,
    t.val,
    (select val from mytable t1 where t1.id < t.id order by t1.id desc limit 1) previousval
from mytable t
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `CREATE` statement of the table you define the column `id` as:

```
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
```

and this means that it will be unique and auto incremented.
But this does not mean that it will always increase.
If you delete a row, the next time that you will insert a new row the *missing* id value may be reused, so the logic that you want to apply will not work.
So as it is explained [here](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html), you must disable the reuse of ids and this can be done by using the keyword `AUTOINCREMENT` in the definition of the column:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ...)
```

Then you can insert new rows like this:

```
INSERT INTO test(val, previousval) VALUES
(100, (SELECT val FROM test ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1));
INSERT INTO test(val, previousval) VALUES       
(200, (SELECT val FROM test ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1));
```